# curl command showing connection timed out but the url is accessible in browser

Tags: curl, timeout

I am executing curl command
curl --output  --url https://100.64.0.6
but the result shows that there is no transfer of data
curl  --url https://100.64.0.6 shows Connection timed out
but the url is accessible in the browser.
Please help in figuring out the issue.

Answer (score -1):

> But the URL is accessible in the browser.

Unfortunately, at this time, it isn't.

Browser caching may be one possible explanation for why you might be able to see the site in your browser when `curl` (or others) can't connect. Essentially, if you have successfully visited the site at some point in the past, your browser may have a local copy of it in order to display it more quickly to you, even though the site is otherwise offline.